# get last occurance with GROUP BY - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Lets say we have this table

```
id    brand      date  
 1    audi       ....
 2    toyota     .....
 3    toyota     ....
 4    audi       ....
 5    audi       .....
```

when i use group by on brand(`select * from table group by brand`) it returns first occurances which is

```
 id   brand      date  
 1    audi       ....
 2    toyota     .....
```

Is it possible to get last occurances with `GROUP BY` clause. Mwith last occurance i mean latest `id` and `date` just like

```
 id   brand      date  
 5    audi       ....
 3    toyota     .....
```

Comment: `ORDER BY date DESC`.

Comment: @BenM i know what is Mysql and how to use it . My aim is getting last occurance with group by as i stated at the headline

Comment: Then why haven't you used `ORDER BY date DESC`?

Comment: i am trying on my table. it does not work. thats why i asked this question. basic things which you expect to work fails with this specific question

Comment: What type is ‘date’?

Comment: @benM  its datetime

Comment: Both solutions definitely work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d51ac/2

Answer (score 2):

```
select brand, max(date) from table group by brand;
```

Comment: i am trying on my table. it does not work. thats why i asked this question. basic things which you expect to work fails with this specific question

Comment: Is the data type on the date field set to a date type? if its set to string, it will not work. If the data is entered into the table in the order in which the events occur, you can do `select brand, substring_index(max(concat(id,'|',date)),'|',-1) from table group by brand;`